# Combining viewport visibility with DrawSVG

Tags: jquery, viewport, window-resize, gsap

So I was trying to execute an DrawSVG animation when it was visible in the viewport, and I came across [this medium post](https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2). I've tried to get this to work for my own code, but I've come across a problem where the paths disappear when the window is scrolled or resized. Here's the code I'm working with. Any help?

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
        TweenMax.from('#bstem', .1, {drawSVG: '0'}, {ease: Power3.easeIn});
        TweenMax.from('#beth', 1, {drawSVG: '0'}, {ease: Power3.easeIn}).delay(.1);
        TweenMax.from('#jacobs', 1.25, {drawSVG: '0'}, {ease: Power3.easeIn}).delay(.9);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/benhullinger/ptpjn9rg

Answer (score 0):

It's very common for resize or scroll events to fire multiple times since users normally drag a window out or scroll down multiple pixels.

The reason why they're disappearing is because the handler fires off multiple times before the animation finishes.

A from animation works by changing the target value from it's current value to the provided value. As the animation is running, it's current value is changing. If the .from animation starts running again before the first animation finishes, the ending value for the second animation changes from the first call. This results in the animation's distorted look.

To avoid multiple calls, you could add a boolean variable to check if the animation is currently running and update that boolean to false at the end of your animation.

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

 var isAnimating = false;
 var updateCheck = function() {
    isAnimating = false;
 }

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {

  if (!isAnimating) {
      isAnimating = true;
      TweenMax.from('#bstem', .1, {drawSVG: 0, ease: Power3.easeIn});
      TweenMax.from('#beth', 1, {drawSVG: 0, ease: Power3.easeIn}).delay(.1);
      TweenMax.from('#jacobs', 1.25, {drawSVG: 0, ease: Power3.easeIn, onComplete: updateCheck}).delay(.9);
  }
});
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll)

> Since scroll events can fire at a high rate, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout or customEvent, as follows. Note however that input events and animation frames are fired at about the same rate and therefore the optimization below is often unnecessary.